# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - Error even when Table exists and Select query runs fine

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am getting this error when I am trying to use the table in a Stored Procedure.
When I do a select * from table, i get results. But when I put it in the Stored Procedure (join with other table) and compile, I get the error,
Error(269,17): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: only select from that table works in stored procedure ?

Comment: Perhaps you only have access to the table via a grant to a **role**.  You need a direct grant to your **schema** to use the table in a procedure.

Answer (score 4):

To use a table from one schema in a stored procedure owned by another schema, the procedure's schema needs a direct grant on the table:

```
grant select on ALPS.CUST_LOOKUP_DTL to myschema;
```

A grant to a role that the schema has is **not** enough:

```
grant select on ALPS.CUST_LOOKUP_DTL to some_role;
grant some_role to myschema;
```

In this case `myschema` can select from the table, but its procedures cannot.

Comment: The general concept is correct. However, Oracle procedures can be defined either with definer's rights (the default) or invoker's rights. The procedure's owner (schema) is relevant only for definer's rights procedures. If the procedure's owner has all the required rights and the procedure will **still** not work, that is often a sign that the procedure was written with invoker's rights (the user who invokes the procedure).

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you execute what you have in your stored procedure? You mention  a join table - that not the same as  select * from table. You may have to fully qualify the table name by schema name.

select * from   schema.table;

Comment: I use: select * from ALPS.CUST_LOOKUP_DTL and in join also i do, INNER JOIN ALPS.CUST_LOOKUP_DTL